# Ng-style not working for background

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I need to set background of element from configuration object through `ng-style`, but I can't do that for some unknown reason, it's really weird for me and I really can't find the reason why.

**The element I'm trying to configure:**

```
<div id="progress-l" ng-style="{ 'width': pblc.options.width, 'height': pblc.options.height, 'background': plbc.options.color }"></div>
```

`pblc` stands for controller here, I'm using `controllerAs` option

**The configuration object:**

```
this.progressLOptions = {
    color: '#F0F3F4',
    width: '200px',
    height: '20px',
};
```

The weirdest thing is that width and height are setted, in rendered html I see this:

```
<div id="progress-l" ng-style="{ 'width': pblc.options.width, 'height': pblc.options.height, 'background': plbc.options.color }" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
</div>
```

I really have no idea how can ng-style work like so. Is there some issue with background I wasn't able to find?

Comment: what is `pblc.options`, As I can see you have `progressLOptions`,, have you messed up with scope variable name?

Comment: @PankajParkar nope, I just use `controllerAs` for directive, if it was naming, height and width won't be setted too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer:
You have a typo -  `plbc.options.color` instead of `pblc.options.color`**

The most likely reason is that `plbc.options.color` is undefined, empty, not in scope or misconfigured. This is in case there's no syntax error of course.

Try outputting it as an expression in the template - `{{plbc.options.color}}` and check it.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed your code a bit, Please look at this

```
    <div id="progress-l" ng-style="{ 'width': progressLOptions.width, 'height': progressLOptions.height, 'background': progressLOptions.color }" style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
   </div>
```

JS

```
   $scope.progressLOptions = {
    color: '#000',
     width: '200px',
    height: '20px',
   };
```

It is working. Use $scope instead of this or else if you want to you this.progressLoptions then in HTML use

```
<body ng-controller="somename as controllerName"> 
and then access this using somename.functionName
```

Demo : https://jsbin.com/zihazi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thank you for answer, it's correct, but it turned out, I had a typo

Comment: Thatz cool !! That is why I made the demo that your logic is correct but somewhere there is a mistake .. !  Anyways solved at atlast. Cheers !!